# XSLT (1.0): When getting the content of a node, is it possible to ignore/skip part of it (or a sub-element)?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have xml code similar to:

```
<body>Text Here1.
</body>
<body><Title>Title</Title>Text Here2.
</body>
<body>Text Here3.
</body>
```

And I'm using the following code in my XSLT:

```
<xsl:when test="@name='body'">
<p> 
<xsl:value-of select='normalize-space(node())'/>
</p>
</xsl:when>
```

What's the best mechanism to ignore that  subelement in the second node, or perhaps apply special formatting to it (let's say I wanted to bold that text) within the node?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When using XSLT to handle hierarchical structures it is common to use apply-templates, which allows you to recursively traverse the XML input. The example below will encapsulate text within `body` elements with a `paragraph` element and encapsulate text within `Title` elements within `bold` elements. All other elements will be ignored.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="body">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Title">
    <b>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </b>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select='normalize-space(.)'/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```